# PHP Clone/Duplicate/Move a Method From One Object to Another

Tags: php, function, object

I have searched around for about an hour or so. I keep finding articles on the WRONG topic; "clone methods" coming up with a method *called* clone; *checking* for duplicate methods; *refactoring* ... THESE are NOT what I am looking for.

What I have is a very generic & basic request, but challenging considering I haven't found an article discussing it. I'd like to move methods from one object to another. Suppose I create two generic objects:

```
class Test {
    private function test0($param=null) {echo 'test0';}
    protected function test1($param=null) {echo 'test1';}
    public function test2($param=null) {echo 'test2';}
    public function test3($param=null) {echo 'test3';}
}
$test = new Test();
$copy = new stdClass();
```

How do I search for the methods within `$test`, and duplicate them inside of `$copy`? Additionally, I do not want to just copy everything. Suppose I only want to copy `test0()`, `test1()`, and `test2()`.

Then, I would like to delete the methods from `$test` one-by-one (but not in a mass-pruning). I want manual control over copying, duplicating, and deleting the methods.

Comment: But why? OOP already offers numerous techniques for doing this without "cloning". such as extending a base class (which is probably what you want), interfaces, abstract classes, or traits

Comment: I want dynamic interchange of methods, and not hard-coded blanket statements.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is not javascript.  Without knowing your reasons, it sounds like you might want to look into like Dependency Injection/Inversion of control.

Alternatively, there is a PHP extension called [runkit](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php) that very directly would allow you to add/remove methods.  So you could simply have a Base class with all the methods, and use runkit to remove any ones you don't want.  Runkit hasn't been updated for php7 however.

With that said, traits are the closest to "predefined methods you can add to any class."  In conjunction with the built in [PHP magic method __call](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call), you could rig something up like what they did with [this trait based library (spatie/macroable)](https://github.com/spatie/macroable).

In general there are many disadvantages to writing, testing and running code like this.  As the old saying goes: There's more than one way to shear a sheep.